# What does 我三谁了 mean in 我也不知道，我刷四绝朋友告诉我有人刷喇叭骂我小三，我不知道我怎么就小三了，我三谁了?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

Could anyone explain to what 我三谁了 mean in

> 我也不知道，我刷四绝朋友告诉我有人刷喇叭骂我小三，我不知道我怎么就小三了，**我三谁了**?!

I know that the whole sentence more or less means "I don’t know, my best friend told me that someone used the world speaker to scold me as a mistress, to scold me as a mistress, .......?!

What does 我三谁了 exactly mean?

It seems to be a very easy to understand sentence but I just cannot understand the 三 there.  If I'm I'm taking a guess I would say that it's "Who is the third?" but if it's that then I have a hard time understanding it inside the sentence.

Comment: Quote:- "...just cannot understand the 三 there.......I have a hard time understanding it inside the sentence" The "三" or "小三", within the context of the whole sentence is an euphemism for a "mistress", that is like a 3rd wife, and not a mistress in the Western sense of a kept woman. So, 我三谁了? is a truncated answer to the previous sentence, namely, 我不知道我怎么就小三了. In full, 我三谁了 would be paraphrased as 我是谁的小三？or words to that effect.

Comment: BTW, if a man has 3 wives, there are called --- 老大 / 老婆，(1st wife); 老二 / 二奶，(2nd wife); 老三 / 小三, (3rd wife) Also all wives other than the 1st wife are also known as 小老婆.

Comment: @WayneCheah No, actually, 小三 and 二奶 mean the same thing "second wife". 三 in 小三 denotes the sense of third person involved in two-person relationship(a couple). A relevant term is 第三者.

Comment: 小三，二奶，第三者: all these terms are referring to illegal  relationship outside marriage. When this word became popular, second wife is already illegal in PRC. So there is no room for the discussion "if the man have two wife".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

三 is forced to be a verb in this sentence. 三了A means 成了A 的小三. But this is only meaningful under the context.

This is understandable because its structure is similar to other sentences' structure. For example: 他是小偷， 他偷了我的钱。 He is a thief. He stole me money.  The 小三 and 三了x  are similar to 小偷 and 偷了x .

Answer (score 2):

This sentence is not grammatically correct, and will not be understood without context. However, with the full context, I think most natives would be able to understand it.

Here it means "to whom I became a mistress?"